# How to use formula to change the font colour in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can anyone share me some light on how to use formula to change the font colour in Excel?

I have a string like this:

[image]

And I need to highlight the words inputted by the user into red color.

Anyone have any idea?

We can use either conditional formatting or formula to do it.

Can anyone share me some idea?

If we cannot change color, changing the font face (Bold/Italic) is also acceptable, but only change the words that was inputted by the user.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do this with a formula or conditional formatting.

Comment: What about VBA?

Comment: That is definitely possible as long as the String is indeed text and not a formula like `="He is the best boy in the school."`

Comment: Could you share a screenshot or describe where the data is located (headers, the columns, the first row of data...) to possibly get a VBA solution? The idea is to write a code that would automatically monitor any changes in the cells, **that contain values, not formulas**, of the `String` and `User input` columns, and appropriately modify the result in the cells of the `Expected result` column.